# Nullreferenceexception is unhandled by user code C# (ThumbCache.db File)

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, oop, nullreferenceexception

I'm working on project to open Thumbscache.db files located at

```
C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
```

**What is ThumbCache.db or Thumbs.db is?**

*On computers running Microsoft Windows, a thumbnail cache is used to store thumbnail images for Windows Explorer when thumbnail view is enabled. This process allows images to display faster because these smaller images do not need to be recalculated every time a user visits the folder containing them.*

**Problem statement:**

I've found a library that can help access/read these(thumbscache) files, so to
 access/read these files library need a path to the files and filename.
 Problem I'm facing is that when I gave path location to the file its
 show my object reference null error, I've debugged my code and checked
 it and path is store in form of string.

Attached images will help to elaborate what my issues is.

[image]

In debugging phase i goto the reference of library class which accept the filepath/filename have following code:

```
namespace ThumbDBLib
{
    public class ThumbDB
    {
        public ThumbDB(string thumbDBFile);

        public byte[] GetThumbData(string filename);
        public string[] GetThumbfiles();
    }
}
```

And i call and desribe my location to the file is in following code:

```
string ThumbDb = (Server.MapPath(".") + "\\thumbs.db");
            if (File.Exists(ThumbDb))
            {
                ThumbDB ThumbLib = new ThumbDB(ThumbDb);
            }
```

Here is the attached image of error

[image]

Comment: As this error occurs in the third party library, you will need to contact it's support. If it's open source, you could download it's source and debug it yourself.

Comment: @nvoigt thanks for recommendation I'm looking for source code of this library. Have you ever worked on thumbcache ? can you suggest me anything related to how to read its content?

Comment: Check your permissions to accessing the file!

Comment: @mjwills to find the exact value please see the 1st attached image. While in debugging phase i check it and value is path to the file.

Comment: No, I not running application on IIS and haven't specify any account yet.

Comment: So, are you running under IIS?

Comment: And, if you are, what identity is being used by your app pool?